# How to add space between variables in twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, template-engine

It's a pretty simple question, but I didn't find the answer yet.

This code:

```
{{ civilite }}{{ nom }}{{ prenom }}
```

Prints MRJOHSONBarry

I want to add space between the variables, how could I do it?

Comment: _how could I do it?_ - ... adding a space between the variables. `{{ civilite }} {{ nom }} {{ prenom }}`

Comment: it didn't worked :x
I also tried {{' '}}

Comment: Does anyone know why adding actual spaces doesn't work? I have a site where this randomly stopped working so I'm having to go through and add `{{ " " }}` everywhere. Maybe related to me recently upgrading to PHP 7.4?

Comment: Never mind, I probably need to update Twig for PHP 7.4 support. See https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3248

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If {{ civilite }} {{ nom }} {{ prenom }} doesn't work...

how about

```
{{ civilite }}&nbsp;{{ nom }}&nbsp;{{ prenom }}?
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks!  (I can accept your answer in 8 minutes haha)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if it's good but I simply use this. Tell me if I'm right :

```
{{ firstname }}{{ " " }}{{ lastname }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the concatenation is the right choice here, when it's only for variable :

```
{{ var ~ " " ~ var2 }}
```

But when it's **for variable and string**, I guess that the **1rst choice would be enough** :

```
{{ var }}&nbsp;My string
```

instead of 
`{{ var ~ " My string" }}` (Not if you want apply filter on the string)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
{{ civilite~" "~nom~" "~prenom  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the problem of needing `&nbsp;` on Twig v2.7.4 and cured it by moving to v3.1.1