# Two html classes with twig variables

Tags: html, class, twig

I want to have an html element with two classes defined by twig variables.
I can do it with one twig variable and they both work separately. But once I try to have them together, only the first class is effective.
I searched on the forum but found only about twig classes or two classes direct in html.
With Twig I have:

```
<p class={{"type#{item.type1}"}}> Paragraph </p>
```

In html it should be:

```
<p class="type1 type2"}}
```

When I try to combine both as below, it does not work:

```
<p class={{"type#{item.type1} type#{item.type2}"}} > Paragraph </p>
```

I also have tried the other concat method with `~` but without sucess.
[How to concatenate strings in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704253/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-twig)

And instead of the space I have tried to add `&nbsp;` as explained here also unsucessful:
[How to add space between variables in twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365322/how-to-add-space-between-variables-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot the wrap your attribute value in quotes. `HTML` will treat the 2nd class as another attribute, not being part of the class attribute

```
<p class="{{"type#{item.type1} type#{item.type2}"}}">Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked. I thought the quotes contained within {{ }} were wraping the attribute.

Comment: No because twig will treat those as the start and the end of string e.g `{{ "foo" }}` will output `foo`